# How to enable drag and drop on double click of a image?

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I am working on drag and drop of images.my drag and drop is working fine.when i drag any image from sidebar and drop it then it shows a control box with dragged item and all this is working fine. Now i need to do the same functionality on click or double click of a image.when user will click any image in sidebar then that image will be automatically dropped in the dropable div area. This is my drag and drop code. Do i need to do same code again on double click of an image?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () 
{
 dragablediv();

}); 

function dragablediv()
{

    var x = null;
    jQuery(".get-image .drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    revert: true,
    /* stop: function (event, ui) { ... } */

});

    jQuery(".droppable").droppable({
        accept: '.drag',
        activeClass: "drop-area",
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            if (jQuery(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {

                x = ui.helper.clone(); 
                ui.helper.remove(); 

                jQuery("#droppable .resize-img").css({"display":"inline-table"});
                /* To show Controls first time on Dragged Image*/
                var droppedItemId = ui.draggable.attr("data-item-id");
                jQuery(".controls ").attr("controls-item-id",droppedItemId);

                jQuery("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide(); // To show Controls
                jQuery(".controls").show();
                dragEl        = jQuery(this); 
                stopPosition  = dragEl.position(); 
                var height = x.height();  // To show the controls with exact position
                var width = x.width(); //alert("stoppos"+stopPosition+"leftpos"+leftPos);
                var topPos = ui.position.top;
                var leftPos = ui.position.left;
                var mytop = topPos+height;
                var myleft = leftPos + width /2; 
                    //alert("left"+leftPos);        
                jQuery(".controls").css({"top": mytop , "left":myleft, "display":"block"});

                x.draggable({   
                    helper: 'original', 
                    cursor: 'move',
                    containment: '#droppable',
                    tolerance: 'fit',

                    drop: function (event, ui) { 
                        jQuery(ui.draggable).remove();

                    },
                    drag: function() {

                    },
                    stop: function() {

                        dragEl        = jQuery(this);
                        stopPosition  = dragEl.position();
                        var leftPos =    dragEl.position().left; 
                        var topPos =     dragEl.position().top; 
                        stopOffset  = dragEl.offset();
                        document_id   = dragEl.data("document-id");
                        signer_id     = dragEl.data("signer-id");
                        var height = x.height();
                        var width = x.width();
                        var mytop = stopPosition.top+height;
                        //var myleft = stopPosition.left + width /2; 

                        jQuery(".controls").css({"top": mytop , "left":myleft, "display":"block"});


                        dataItem = jQuery(this).attr('data-item-id');
                        jQuery("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
                        jQuery(".controls").hide();
                        jQuery(this).closest(".drag").find(".ui-resizable-handle").show();
                        jQuery(".controls").show();
                        jQuery(".controls ").attr("controls-item-id",dataItem); 

                    } 

                }); 

                x.resizable({
                    maxHeight: jQuery('#droppable').height(),
                    maxWidth: jQuery('#droppable').width(), 
                    aspectRatio: true,
                    helper: "ui-resizable-helper", 
                    handles: "nw, ne, sw,se" 
                });  

                //x.addClass('remove');

                x.appendTo('.droppable');

            }
        } 
    });
}
```